# Why is rejection sampling with acceptance probability 2/3 for Beta(2,2) not slower than `rbeta(N,2,2)`?

Tags: simulation, beta-distribution, rejection-sampling

I was trying to illustrate that rejection sampling is inefficient when an alternative approach is available that does not throw away samples. (This post obviously is a candidate for migration to SO, but I feel that there might also be a statistical aspect to it.)

My example was going to be simulating $Beta(2,2)$ variates with a rejection algorithm and  `rbeta(N,2,2)`. My code is as follows:

```
# densityatmode <- dbeta(.5,2,2)=1.5
rejectionsampling_beta22 <- function(N){
     px <- runif(N,min=0,max=1)
     py <- runif(N,min=0,max=1.5)
     ikeep <- (py < 6*px*(1-px))
     return(px[ikeep])
}

samples <- 1500000
```

The acceptance probability is `area under density/area in box`, `area under density` of course equal to one, so 1/1.5, or equivalently, we need 1.5 as many candidate samples when using rejection.

```
library(microbenchmark)
result <- microbenchmark(rejectionsampling_beta22(1.5*samples),rbeta(samples,2,2))
```

The result, which is surprising to me, as I felt that rejection of 1/3 of the draws should be wasteful:

```
Warning message:
In microbenchmark(rejectionsampling_beta22(1.5 * samples), rbeta(samples,  :
  Could not measure a positive execution time for 33 evaluations.
> result
Unit: nanoseconds
                                    expr       min        lq         mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 rejectionsampling_beta22(1.5 * samples) 180171443 254891504 248482870.58 257005186 258866373 329533988   100  b 
                    rbeta(samples, 2, 2) 253091893 254717640 261602707.69 257391248 259902160 333055032   100   c
                                   neval         0         0        63.97         1         1       604   100 a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [Cheng & Feast Gamma generator](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/~kroese/montecarlohandbook/probdist/) code, on which R rbeta and rgamma functions are based:

```
function x=gamrnd_cheng(alpha)
% Gamma(alpha,1) generator using Cheng--Feast method
% Algorithm 4.35
c1=alpha-1; c2=(alpha-1/(6*alpha))/c1; c3=2/c1; c4=1+c3;
c5=1/sqrt(alpha);
flag=0;
while flag==0;
    U1=rand; U2=rand;
    if alpha>2.5
        U1=U2+c5*(1-1.86*U1);
    end
       W=c2*U2/U1;
     flag=(U1<1)&&(U1>0)&&(((c3*U1+W+1/W)<c4)||((c3*log(U1)-log(W)+W)<1));
end
x=c1*W;
```

which can be recycled into a Beta generator at about the same cost. It uses two uniforms, plus a rejection condition, so for the values of $(\alpha,\beta)$ that you picked, i.e., for a rejection probability of $1/3$, the accept-reject algorithm may be equally efficient. However, you should also run the comparison for larger non-integer values of $(\alpha,\beta)$ to check whether or not the Cheng & Feast Gamma generator remains efficient.

For instance, [Joe Whittaker's Beta $\mathfrak{B}(\alpha,\beta)$ generator](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347003?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) has a rejection condition of the form$$U_1^{1/\alpha}+U_2^{1/\beta}>1$$which occurs with increasing frequency as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ increase. I remember Luc Devroye mentioning that, for $\mathfrak{G}(\alpha,1)$ distributions, it is not possible to find a bound on the computing time that is independent of $\alpha$...

Comment: Thanks +1! This is C++? Matlab?

Comment: This sounds like matlab. I have added the reference to Dick Kroese's website where I found it. Along with other Beta generators.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Xi'an's suggestion, the result in the question indeed seems to be an artifact of the particular (small) parameters chosen. In particular, when choosing higher $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that the beta density becomes more concentrated with a correspondingly higher density at the mode, such that a larger box needs to be constructed around the beta density in the basic rejection algorithm, such that the acceptance probability decreases, the result disappears and `rbeta` is much more efficient.

Here is an example for $\alpha=\beta=10.2$:

```
# densityatmode <- dbeta(.5,10.2,10.2)=3.559877
# precompute the beta density:
# gamma(20.4)/gamma(10.2)^2=1231365
rejectionsampling_betaab <- function(N){
  px <- runif(N,min=0,max=1)
  py <- runif(N,min=0,max=3.559877)
  #ikeep <- (py < dbeta(px,10.2,10.2))
  ikeep <- (py < 1231365*px^9.2*(1-px)^9.2)
  return(px[ikeep])
}

AcceptanceProbability <- 1/(3.559877)
samples <- 1e5

library(microbenchmark)
result <- microbenchmark(rejectionsampling_betaab(1/AcceptanceProbability*samples),rbeta(samples,10.2,10.2))
```

The result now clearly favors `rbeta`:

```
> result
Unit: milliseconds
                                                        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 rejectionsampling_betaab(1/AcceptanceProbability * samples) 417.46861 426.16041 469.10049 430.37921 485.60090 635.9086   100
                                  rbeta(samples, 10.2, 10.2)  90.39748  90.94824  94.24759  91.52765  92.51329 264.5119   100
```